# image.Decode fail on golang embed

Tags: image, go, decode

The purpose of this program in to decode a img embedded with "embed".
The image (`bu.png`) is in the same directory of the ***main.go***.

- It seem that the embed way fail to set the exact same resources

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    _ "embed"
    "image"
)

var (
    //go:embed bu.png
    img []byte
)

func main() {

    a  := bytes.NewBuffer(img)
    a, b, e := image.Decode()
    println(e.Error())
    //  image: unknown format

    println(b)
    //

    println(a)
    // (0x0,0x0)

    // println(string(img))
    // the text of the image seem a little different between nano

}
```

the image data shold be in the img variabile cause "embed" import

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't an `embed` thing.  [You have to import the individual libraries you want to support.](https://pkg.go.dev/image#pkg-overview)  Their initialization will register their formats for use by  `image.Decode`.  To quote the aforelinked,

> Decoding any particular image format requires the prior registration of a decoder function.

Try adding an import like,

```
_ "image/png"
```

I tested this with the following, which should convince you that `embed` is irrelevant:

```
package main

import (
    _ "embed"
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "image"
    //_ "image/png"
    //_ "image/jpeg"
    //_ "image/gif"
    "os"
)

var (
    //go:embed bu.png
    img []byte
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("bu.png")
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Couldn't open file: %w", err))
    }
    defer f.Close()
    fmt.Println(image.Decode(f))
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(img)
    fmt.Println(image.Decode(buf))

}
```